# FieldError at /favourites/ Cannot resolve keyword 'favpost' into field. Choices are: author, author_id

Tags: django, django-models

I have error  FieldError at /en/account/profile/favourites/ Cannot resolve keyword 'favpost' into field. Choices are: author, author_id

This spanning can be as deep as you’d like.

It works backwards, too. While it can be customized, by default you refer to a “reverse” relationship in a lookup using the lowercase name of the model.

This example retrieves all Post objects which have at least one favPost whose user=request.user

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    excerpt = models.TextField()

class favPost(models.Model):        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='postfv', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userfv', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post


def favourite_list(request):
    new2 = Post.objects.filter( favpost__user=request.user )        
    return render(request, 'accounts/favourites.html', {'new':  new2  } )
```

Comment: Is the `post` `ForeignKey` indented at the right side of the line with `favPost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for the `ForeignKey` to post is `related_name='postfv'`, you thus query with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def favourite_list(request):
    new2 = Post.objects.filter(postfv__user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'accounts/favourites.html', {'new': new2})
```

You should furthermore put the `post` `ForeignKey` as field under the `favPost`, so:

```
class FavPost(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='postfv', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userfv', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.post)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).